# How to access static of templated class from template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to write a template using the CRTP pattern. What I would like is for the template to access a `static const` in the templated class.

My template look like this in it's own header:

```
template <class T> foo {
  static const int readValue = T::value
}
```

And I inherit from the template like this (in another header file):

```
class fooImpl: foo<fooImpl> {
  static const int value = 42; 
}
```

However, clang complains:

**No member named 'value' in 'fooImpl'**

I think I get the chicken and egg problem here. The template does not know the definition of `fooImpl`, and hence, cannot know that it has the member `value` when it is instantiated.

But how do I work around it? Is there a way to get the compile time propagation of the const value into the instantiated template?

Answer (score 6):

The `foo<fooImpl>` base class is instantiated in the base-class list but `fooImpl` is an incomplete type at that point, and `foo::value` has not been declared yet.

You can move the definition of the static member later:

```
template <class T> struct foo {
  static const int readValue;
};

class fooImpl: foo<fooImpl> {
  static const int value = 42; 
};

template<class T> const int foo<T>::readValue = T::value;
```

However, this won't allow you to use `readValue` as a compile-time constant in the body of `foo`.

Comment: This won't work unless foo and fooImpl are the same file right?

Comment: You can keep them in separate headers. The out-of-class definition of `readValue` doesn't need to be after the definition of `fooImpl` it just needs to be out-of-class.  You can't put the out-of-class definition in a non-header file though, without carefully managing explicit instantiations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need readValue to be compile time constant. My solution currently is to have a third "helper class" fooConsts that contains the constants I would normally put in fooImpl. I can then control when fooConst is declared (before both the template and fooImpl) and both can see then see the consts. Very ugly, but I guess that is what a language that still thinks headers files is a good idea drives you to do.